# How do I locate php.ini?

Tags: linux, unix, php, webserver, web-development

I installed php on the server and php_info(); displays:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   /home/gmcnulty/php
```

However, I don't see anything there nor do I see any php directory?

How do I locate the php directory and specifically the php.ini file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Try going into `/etc` and executing `find -name "php.ini"` This should tell you where php.ini is located.

Comment: listed 6 directories followed by "Permission denied" - guess that mean I can't make changes to it?

Comment: Hm, were you able to find the file you're looking for? The Permission denied message is there probably because you aren't running the command in superuser mode. Try sudo find -name "php.ini" and that should go away.

Answer (score 2):

If you can access the CLI, typing `php --ini` will show you which .ini file PHP is trying to load.

It's possible, but unlikely, that you have no php.ini file at all, and could create one in the place that `php_info();` suggests.

If you are on shared hosting, you may not be able to navigate highter than `/home/gmcnulty`, so in this case you should look for the `php` directory in the highest level you can access.

It is normal for php.ini to live in `/etc`, but I have also seen it installed in `/var/lib` before.